# ¿Como puedo crear un lista de tuplas que reciba (nombre,edad)?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Dado un archivo que contenga una lista de nombres en cada línea, y un archivo que contenga una lista de edades en cada línea, cree un
nuevo archivo nombres_edades.txt que contenga en cada línea el nombre y la edad de cada persona en el formato nombre,edad.

Tengo lo siguiente:

Archivos txt nombres y edades

```
alberto,bryan,carlos,dario

erick,fabricio,german,hugo
```

```
56,32,11,55

23,12,21,32
```

```html
def leerArchivo(archivo):
    lectura = open(archivo, 'r', encoding='utf-8')
    lista = []
    for linea in lectura:
        lista.append(linea.strip().split(','))
    lectura.close()
    return lista
nombres = np.array(leerArchivo('nombres.txt'))
edades = np.array(leerArchivo('edades.txt'),dtype=int)
```

Evidentemente, se crean 2 matrices, pero no entiendo cómo deberia hacer el recorrido para formar tuplas elemento por elemento, por ejemplo,(german,21) -Si es que son necesarias las tuplas-

Y añadir todas esas tuplas a una lista o, en su defecto, añadirlas al archivo a crear.

Answer (score 0):

Para obtener el archivo de salida no necesitas ni siquiera almacenar en memoria su contenido mediante los arrays. Solo necesitas iterar a la par sobre las filas de ambos archivos usando `zip` y luego sobre cada pareja nombre:edad de la misma forma. Por ejemplo:

```
with open('nombres.txt') as nomfile, open('edades.txt') as efile:
    with open("nombres_edades.txt", "w") as outfile:
        for nf, ef in zip(nomfile, efile):
            for nom, ed in zip(nf.rstrip().split(','), ef.rstrip().split(',')):
                outfile.write(f"{nom},{ed}\n")
```

Dado que en la práctica tus archivos son csv, lo apropiado es usar el módulo [`csv`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/csv.html) de la biblioteca estándar:

```
import csv


with open('nombres.txt') as nomfile, open('edades.txt') as efile:
    nom_reader = csv.reader(nomfile, delimiter=',')
    edad_reader = csv.reader(efile, delimiter=',')
    with open("nombres_edades.txt", "w") as outfile:
        out_writer = csv.writer(outfile, delimiter=',')
        for nomf, edadf in zip(nom_reader, edad_reader):
            out_writer.writerows(zip(nomf, edadf))
```

En cualquier caso la salida sería (nombres_edades.txt):

> alberto,56
>   bryan,32
>   carlos,11
>   dario,55
>   erick,23
>   fabricio,12
>   german,21
>   hugo,32

En realidad con `zip` conseguimos exactamente tuplas de la forma `("nombre", "edad")`. Si quisieras una matriz, similar a lo que inicialmente pretendías con los arrays, en vez de guardarlo directamente en el archivo de salida basta con algo como:

```
import csv


with open('nombres.txt') as nomfile, open('edades.txt') as efile:
    nom_reader = csv.reader(nomfile, delimiter=',')
    edad_reader = csv.reader(efile, delimiter=',')
    lista =  [list(zip(*pair)) for pair in zip(nom_reader, edad_reader)]
```

la salida es:

> ```
> >>> lista
>
> [[('alberto', '56'), ('bryan', '32'), ('carlos', '11'), ('dario', '55')],
>  [('erick', '23'), ('fabricio', '12'), ('german', '21'), ('hugo', '32')]]
> ```

Dado que todas tus filas son del mismo tamaño, por poder se puede hacer usando solo NumPy:

```
import numpy as np


nombres = np.loadtxt("nombres.txt", delimiter=",", dtype=str)
edad = np.loadtxt("edades.txt", delimiter=",", dtype=str)
nom_edad = np.stack((nombres, edad), -1)
nom_edad = nom_edad.reshape(np.multiply(*nom_edad.shape[:2]), 2)
np.savetxt("nombres_edades.txt", nom_edad, delimiter=",", fmt='%s')
```

`nombres` y `edad` son arrays con los datos de los archivos similares a los que tu habías conseguido.

Con `numpy.stack` conseguimos el paso por el que preguntabas, unir ambos:

```
[[['alberto' '56']
  ['bryan' '32']
  ['carlos' '11']
  ['dario' '55']]

 [['erick' '23']
  ['fabricio' '12']
  ['german' '21']
  ['hugo' '32']]]
```

Con `reshape` eliminamos la dimensión extra causada por las filas de los csv, pasando de un array 3D a un array 2D (necesario para poder guardarlo en el archivo de salida):

```
[['alberto' '56']
 ['bryan' '32']
 ['carlos' '11']
 ['dario' '55']
 ['erick' '23']
 ['fabricio' '12']
 ['german' '21']
 ['hugo' '32']]
```

Comment: A partir de [Python 3.10](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.10.html#parenthesized-context-managers) puedes formatear una colección de gestores de contexto en múltiples líneas, que probablemente es la causa por la que anidas usando expresiones `with`